# pandas: group or pivot table by a column horizonally rather than vertically

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have got data that looks like this

```
data = [['01/01/2000', 'aaa', 101, 102],
        ['01/02/2000', 'aaa', 201, 202],
        ['01/01/2000', 'bbb', 301, 302],
        ['01/02/2000', 'bbb', 401, 402],]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'id', 'val1', 'val2'])
df

date        id      val1    val2 
01/01/2000  aaa     101     102
01/02/2000  aaa     201     202
01/01/2000  bbb     301     302
01/02/2000  bbb     401     402
```

I would like this data to be transformed to look like this - where it's grouped horizonally by the id column

```
            aaa             bbb
date        val1    val2    val1    val2    
01/01/2000  101     102     301     302     
01/02/2000  201     202     401     402
```

Closest i have gotten so far is: `df.set_index(['date', 'id']).unstack(level=1)`, but this does not quite do it:

```
val1    val2
id  aaa bbb aaa bbb
date                
01/01/2000  101 301 102 302
01/02/2000  201 401 202 402
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
out = (df.set_index(['date', 'id'])
         .unstack(level=1)
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1))
print (out )
id          aaa       bbb     
           val1 val2 val1 val2
date                          
01/01/2000  101  102  301  302
01/02/2000  201  202  401  402
```

Or use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
out = (df.melt(['date', 'id'])
         .pivot(index='date', columns=['id', 'variable'], values='value')
         .sort_index(axis=1))
```

Comment: nice. thanks. is there any performance benefits of going with one solution over the other?

Comment: @mike01010 - I think it depends of data - how many unique `date`s, `id`s ? How many rows? Best test both solutions.

Comment: there may be about 40K-50k rows of unique date + ids

Comment: @mike01010 - I guess second one.

Comment: thanks. if i can ask one more question...when i try to convert this data to a dict or csv, there is a multi-index which hass values like (aaa, val1) and (aaa, val2).  is it possible to have this converted such that each row is actually a row, with nans for any missing column?  maybe i open a different question for this...

Comment: @mike01010 - Do you need `pd.concat([out.columns.to_frame().T, out]).to_csv('test2.csv', header=None)` ?

Comment: i will try that, thank you. for now i ended up simply dropping that first level of the header: ```df.columns.droplevel()```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and reindex with the [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values:

```
out = (df
   .pivot(index='date', columns='id')
   .swaplevel(axis=1)[df['id'].unique()]
 )
```

This should be faster than `melt` and faster than `sort_index` if there are many columns.

Output:

```
id          aaa       bbb     
           val1 val2 val1 val2
date                          
01/01/2000  101  102  301  302
01/02/2000  201  202  401  402
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['01/01/2000', 'aaa', 101, 102],
        ['01/02/2000', 'aaa', 201, 202],
        ['01/01/2000', 'bbb', 301, 302],
        ['01/02/2000', 'bbb', 401, 402],]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'id', 'val1', 'val2'])
"""print(df)
         date   id  val1  val2
0  01/01/2000  aaa   101   102
1  01/02/2000  aaa   201   202
2  01/01/2000  bbb   301   302
3  01/02/2000  bbb   401   402"""

res = (
    df.set_index(['date', 'id']) 
      .unstack('id')  # Pivot columns based on 'id'
      .sort_index(axis=1)  # Sort columns 
)
"""print(res)

           val1      val2     
id          aaa  bbb  aaa  bbb
date                          
01/01/2000  101  301  102  302
01/02/2000  201  401  202  402
"""
```